# How to use DictVectorizer to convert categorical column

Tags: python, pandas, one-hot-encoding, dictvectorizer

I have dataframe whose some columns (C1 ,C2 ,C3) are categorical ( string)  variable. Data and datatypes   is as following:

```
                 C1           C2           C3           C4           C5  \
4   b'02e197c5'  b'c2ced437'  b'a2427619'  b'3f85ecae'  b'b8c51ab7'
9   b'62770d79'  b'ad984203'  b'ddd956c1'  b'f7f54f97'  b'bbaea1c0'
13  b'7ffd46c3'  b'710103fd'  b'a1407382'  b'f2463ffb'  b'664ff944'
14  b'9a8cb066'  b'7a06385f'  b'417e6103'  b'6faef306'  b'f8990a45'
45  b'6f877ce8'  b'58cc2d25'  b'9b48ba97'  b'f2463ffb'  b'd90dd51f'
```

Datatype:

```
C1        object

C2        object

C3        object
```

Then , I have used  DictVectorizer to apply one-hot-code for string

```
labelTransformer = DictVectorizer(dtype='str')
labelTransformer.fit_transform(clickDataFrame["C1"].astype("str"))
```

But after that , I get error as following:

```
 File "click_main.py", line 60, in <module>
    df2 = labelTransformer.fit_transform(clickDataFrame["C1"].astype("str"))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/dict_vectorizer.py", line 230, in fit_transform
    return self._transform(X, fitting=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/dict_vectorizer.py", line 166, in _transform
    for f, v in six.iteritems(x):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sklearn/externals/six.py", line 439, in iteritems
    return iter(getattr(d, _iteritems)(**kw))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

I have tried alot of  , but I can't find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get one-hot encodings directly from pandas using `pd.get_dummies`. If you want to treat each column independently, you can simply do `pd.get_dummies(df)` or `pd.get_dummies(df.C1)`.

If you want to obtain an indicator for every unique value across all columns, you can use `pd.get_dummies(df.stack()).unstack().swaplevel(0, 1, axis=1)`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is a few years old, but just came across it from a search.

Have you tried transforming your dataframe `to_dict` and then applying the `fit_transform`?

```
labelTransformer = DictVectorizer()
clickDataDict = clickDataFrame.to_dict('records')
encodedData = labelTransformer.fit_transform(clickDataDict)
```